# Reason for error : HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I don't know why I get this error in eclipse web browser when I try to run my NewFile.html.
In my Dummy dynamic web project, I can "call" one of the two servlets from NewFile.html. But, I have purposely made my web.xml such that any url request to this Dummy will be sent to Servlet1 only. I saw the related posts on SO, but found no errors in my code as per the answers given there. I don't know where I am wrong. Please help me to make this work. My code is given below.

**NewFile.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>All roads will lead to servlet 1</h2>

<form method="POST" action="/Dummy/Servlet1">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Servlet1" />
</form>

<form method="POST" action="/Dummy/Servlet2">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Servlet2" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Servlet 1 or 2:**

```
package foo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Servlet1() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 

        out.println("<h1>Welcome to Servlet - 1</h1>");

    }

}
```

**web.xml:**

```
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Servlet1</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>foo.Servlet1</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**EDIT-**

Method added only to Servlet1

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException {

   RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/html/NewFile.html");
   dispatcher.forward(request, response);   

}
```

Project structure

[image]

Comment: You're implementing doPost but not doGet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are sending a GET request to `/context/NewFile.html`. Your web.xml has mapped `Servlet1` as handling requests with pattern `/*`, in other words, everything. So `Servlet1` is used to handle the request to `/NewFile.html`, but it doesn't have a handler method for GET requests, so it responds with a 405.

Comment: Oh. In my previous dynamic web projects, I used to implement only doPost or doGet and it worked. Yes, the web.xml made all the difference. Thanks.

Comment: @borqt What does your doGet do?

Comment: doGet only outputs a message. maybe i should redirect it to NewFile.html using RequestDispatcher ? Can't I just add an exclusion for NewFile.html in web.xml ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev You have to make it do what you want. If you want to render the HTML, forward to it with a `RequestDispatcher`. There are different ways to achieve this result.

Comment: I did that and my tomcat goes into an infinite loop. Posting details now.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Put your files under `WEB-INF` and reference them there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this modifications:
- First for html actions use the following:

```
...
<form method="POST" action="Servlet1">
...
```

and then in the web.xml use the following mapping:

```
...
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Servlet1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```